# svg logo not fully displayed in firefox

Tags: css

so this is my svg logo rendered in chrome:

[image]

and this is what is display in firefox:

[image]

I can't understand why and how it is rendered like this in firefox.

this is the simple code:

`<img src="/img/logo.svg" width="150" height="45" alt="MQSB" />`.

Does any body know how I can fix that ?

**Edit:**

This is the rest of the code... But I don't think it would help.

```
<Navbar className='px-5 mb-5' collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Navbar.Brand as='span'>
            <Link to='/'>
                <img src="/img/logo.svg" width="150" height="45" alt="MQSB" />
            </Link>
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse className='text-center' id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="me-auto">
                {(user && user.token) &&
                    <Link style={{ color: 'white', textDecoration: 'none' }} className='my-1 mx-3' to='/publish-article'>Publier</Link>
                }
                <Link style={{ color: 'white', textDecoration: 'none' }} className='mx-3 my-1' to='/search-article'>Naviguer</Link>
                <Link style={{ color: 'white', textDecoration: 'none' }} className='mx-3 my-1' to='/quizz'>Quizz</Link>
                <Link style={{ color: 'white', textDecoration: 'none' }} className='mx-3 my-1' to='/about'>À propos</Link>
                <Link style={{ color: 'white', textDecoration: 'none' }} className='mx-3 my-1' to='/contact'>Contact</Link>
            </Nav>
            <Nav>
                {(user && user.token) ? <>
                    <NavDropdown align="end" className='text-primary text-center' title={user.infos.username} id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
                        <Link className='text-center' to='/account/settings' style={{ color: 'black', textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                            <NavDropdown.Item as='span'>
                                Mon compte
                            </NavDropdown.Item>
                        </Link>
                        <NavDropdown.Divider />
                        <NavDropdown.Item className='text-center' onClick={logOut}>Déconnexion</NavDropdown.Item>
                    </NavDropdown>
                </> : <>
                    <NavDropdown className='text-primary' align="end" style={{ color: 'black' }} title="Mon compte" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
                        <Link to='/login' style={{ color: 'black', textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                            <NavDropdown.Item as='span' className='text-center'>
                                Connexion
                            </NavDropdown.Item>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to='/register' style={{ color: 'black', textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                            <NavDropdown.Item as='span' className='text-center'>
                                Inscription
                            </NavDropdown.Item>
                        </Link>
                    </NavDropdown>
                </>}
            </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar >
```

Comment: Without the rest of the code of the whole web page is very difficult to help you. But, what you can focus is the next element on the right hand side of the screenshot as it might overlay the image that is "behind" the neighbor element.

Comment: @ino I edited the rest of the code, but when I am inspecting the the webpage, there is no item that overlays the logo...

Comment: Only code of the template is a bit useless as the final results is affected by generated HTML, CSS, JavaScript, user interaction, ad-blockers... Better would be a live demo with the problematic part or URL of the page online.

Comment: @ino monquartiersebouge.fr is the web page, don't know if it can help. And there is no extra css (just boostrap's one)

Comment: Perfect, now I see it is not a problem of the page layout/css/etc. buth the problem is the image itself - if opened image URL in both browsers Chrome shows it correctly, FireFox does not. The image URL: https://monquartiersebouge.fr/img/logo.svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in page HTML/CSS or whatever.

There is probably wrong scaling of the inner images.

1. Open the URL of the image in FireFox https://monquartiersebouge.fr/img/logo.svg
2. Open the Inspector <kbd>CTRL+Shift+I</kbd>
3. Navigate to `svg > defs > image#img2`
4. Set the actual width `1522` to some lower number such as `1100`
5. Now the svg image will be shown in full range without cropping

`<image id="img2" width="1100" height="409" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="data:image/png;...." />`

So review the source image and align inner image dimensions.